# Error when building a interaction SQL Query in Marketing Cloud using a semicolon

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Working in Marketing cloud where we are building a query that splits apart data from a single column into 4 separate columns where the delimiter is a semicolon.

Error is displayed when doing a "check syntax"

Error message: ';' is a reserved word and may not appear in your query.

We cant change the data to use a different delimiter so wanted to know if anyone knows of a work around?

```
select 
c.contactid as subscriber_key 
, coalesce(i.Preferred_Correspondence_Name, i.[first name]) as Preferred_Correspondence_Name 
, i.[email address] as email 
, c.casenumber 
, c.Id as case_salesforce_id 
,party.name as party 
, c.LastModifiedDate as last_modified_date 
, c.CreatedDate as created_date 
, c.Bank_Account_Change__c as bank_account_change 
,'add' as action 
,LTrim(PARSENAME(REPLACE([c.Bank_Account_Change__c],';','.'),4)) as Party_Details 
,LTrim(PARSENAME(REPLACE([c.Bank_Account_Change__c],';','.'),3)) as Party_ID_Details 
,LTrim(PARSENAME(REPLACE([c.Bank_Account_Change__c],';','.'),2)) as Bank_Account_Details 
,LTrim(PARSENAME(REPLACE([c.Bank_Account_Change__c],';','.'),1)) as Start_Date_Details 
from 
ENT.Case_salesforce_2 as c 
inner join ENT.RecordType_Salesforce as rt on c.RecordTypeId = rt.Id 
inner join ENT.account_salesforce as party on party.id = c.accountid 
inner join contact i on i.[subscriber key]= c.contactid 
where 
Type = 'Payments' 
and Sub_Type__c = 'Bank Account Change' 
and Raised_By__c = 'External' 
and Origin = 'Web' 
and rt.Name = 'Financial Enquiries' 
and c.Bank_Account_Change__c is not null
```

Comment: As far as I know, PARSENAME is not supported in SFMC -- at least for now.  Word on the street is that the back-end db is now SQL Server 2016, but the interface validator hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: Adam, do you know if the SQL is ran in its native form, or is it re-compiled behind the scenes? My suspicion is it's the latter.

Comment: It's wrapped in a series of queries and executed, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a delimited field parsing method that works in SFMC, if you'd like to adapt it:

```
SELECT 
  a.uid
  , a.field
  , SUBSTRING(a.field, 1, ISNULL(p1 - 1, LEN(a.field))) field1
  , SUBSTRING(a.field, p1 + 1, ISNULL(p2, LEN(a.field) + 1) - p1 - 1) field2
  , SUBSTRING(a.field, p2 + 1, ISNULL(p3, LEN(a.field) + 1) - p2 - 1) field3
  , SUBSTRING(a.field, p3 + 1, ISNULL(p4, LEN(a.field) + 1) - p3 - 1) field4
  , SUBSTRING(a.field, p4 + 1, ISNULL(p5, LEN(a.field) + 1) - p4 - 1) field5
  , SUBSTRING(a.field, p5 + 1, ISNULL(p6, LEN(a.field) + 1) - p5 - 1) field6
  , SUBSTRING(a.field, p6 + 1, ISNULL(p7, LEN(a.field) + 1) - p6 - 1) field7
from ParseTest a
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', a.field), 0)) b(p1)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', a.field, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', a.field, p2 + 1), 0)) d(p3)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', a.field, p3 + 1), 0)) e(p4)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', a.field, p4 + 1), 0)) f(p5)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', a.field, p5 + 1), 0)) g(p6)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', a.field, p6 + 1), 0)) h(p7)
where isnull(a.field,'') != ''
```

So if `field` contained `1|2|3|4|5|6|7`, the result would be:

```
+-------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| uid   | field         | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 | field6 | field7 |
+-------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 12345 | 1|2|3|4|5|6|7 | 1      | 2      | 3      | 4      | 5      | 6      | 7      |
+-------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Also works if your `field` value has less or more than 7 elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help, managed to get it sorted with the above help. FYI: Salesforce advises also that they are working on an internal project around improving the query validation used in the Query Activity

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to replace ';' with CHAR(59) in your SQL code.

I found the available character codes here:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6022/sql-server-char-function-and-reference-guide/

> The SQL Server CHAR String Function converts any of 256 integer ASCII
> codes to a character value.

Comment: Thanks this helped me with my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to work

```
SELECT DISTINCT Job_Profile__c
FROM ENT.Lead_Salesforce l
WHERE Job_Profile__c LIKE '%AE' + CHAR(59) + '%'
```